# Passing touch event from one component to ListView

Tags: android

I have a simple Button, that has a touch listener. Once it's triggered on ACTION_DOWN action, a ListView appears on top of that button (so that the ListView is under user's finger). 
What I want is to "pass" that touch event from Button to that ListView, so that when moved up/down, the list view would also scroll up/down.

Simply put:

1. User touches a Button
2. A list view appears on covering that button
3. WITHOUT RELEASING A FINGER, user starts moving finger to the top/bottom screen edge,
4. The list view scrolls.

**UPDATE**

I tried making a custom ListView component with `onInterceptTouchEvent` overridden, but I do not clearly get what should go into that method?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom class extending `ListView`, then override the method `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)`. That method gets called whenever a view inside the list is touched.

Comment: that was exactly what I was trying to do, but I do not clearly understand what should be inside `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` methods?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any custom component.

Set your button `onTouchListener` as:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) 
    {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // popup the listView
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // lstPopup is your ListView
                lstPopup.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // do other stuff
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

And set your listView `onTouchListener` as:

```
lstPopup.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            lstPopup.setSelectionFromTop(0, (int) motionEvent.getY());
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```